# How to append user input to existing csv file?

Tags: python, csv, append

I'm trying to append user input to an existing csv. There is no header or index.

```
CSV_ex:

a,b,c
d,e,f
h,i,j


code:
if user_input == 'add':

    x = int(input('How many questions do you want to add?'))
    for _ in range(x):
        new_question = input('Enter your question: \n')
        with open("pyquiz.csv", 'a+') as f:
            f.writelines(new_question)
```

As we know the writelines method doesn't append more than one line. What is an alternative?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you need. Given the input, can you provide the sample output if someone were to pick, say, '2'? Do you want to write multiple columns? I don't see how the bigger idea fits with your sample CSV. Please edit and update your question. Thanks :)

Comment: The for loop runs as many times as x. So if they input 2, the for loop runs 2 times. No, I wanted to write to multiple rows. Below  is the sample output:
How many questions do you want to add? 2
Enter your question: 
q,r,t
Enter your question: 
d,y,i

Comment: Please edit your question and include that information to make it as complete as possible. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u question want to append string to the csv file.

try:

```
new_question = "1,2,3"
with open("pyquiz.csv", 'a+') as f:
    f.writelines(f"{new_question}\n")
```